# is は/が always needed to make a grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-が

I listen to a lot of Japanese music, and a common trend I've seen with a lot of them are to say 「≪pronoun≫≪noun≫」. For example,

> 「あたし猫」 = "I'm a cat."

My question is, is this grammatically correct? I thought you needed は or が to mark the subject/topic, like so:

> 「あたしは猫」/「あたしが猫」= "I'm a cat."

Which would make the former:

> 「あたし猫」 = "I, cat."

But, I know Japanese doesn't abide by English grammar standards, nor does は/が inherently mean "is/am"etc. So, I ask,

1. How would「あたし猫」be translated?
2. Is it grammatically correct? (Even if the English translation turns out to be something like "I, cat."?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It means exactly the same as `あたしは猫`/`あたしが猫`
2. Grammatically it is incorrect. But in reality(at least for Japanese), most of the sentence we speak is not grammatically correct at all when we are talking with friends.
   Ex) `この後何する？`